# Can I import a drone into Argentina?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, argentina, drones

I've got a DJI Phantom, and am planning to take it with me from UK to Buenos Aires, Argentina.

I've heard customs officials can be a bit sticky with drones, Argentina being one country like that? I know in UK you 90% of the time get your bags and walk out, but in Argentina you get your bags and then put them through a scanner, so I'm sure the customs officials will see it.

Will I have any trouble taking it? Will they try and make me pay a tax? Is there anything I should do?

*I found this question, [Can you carry drones on a plane as a carry on?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53190/can-you-carry-drones-on-a-plane-as-a-carry-on-eg-dji-phantom-or-inspire) which helps with taking it on the plane, but my concerned is about customs on arrival, any stickyness, charges etc.*

---

#### Additional Details:

Yes, end result is that the drone will stay in Argentina. It has a value of approximately U$D 1400.00 or £ 1200.00, and is mainly for recreational use, however I may use it for my business from time to time - but guess that it would enter under personal item.

I took it, and well nothing happened - didn't get asked for my customs card, didn't get asked what it was!

**Verdict:** Don't take it unless you are prepared to pay the import charge, but keep quiet and you will probably not be asked about it.

Comment: Are you going to leave it there (import it) or will you take back out of the country? Is it for personal or commercial/business use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to this question.

First:
**Are drones allowed in Argentina?**
According to [this site drones for hobby use](http://thedroneinfo.com/argentinian-drone-regulations/) were allowed in July 2015.
You should check shortly before traveling, but I feel that the chances are good.

Second:
**How much value can you bring into Argentina?**
It looks [like adults can bring goods](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/AR-Argentina-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) to a value of $US 300 and minors (under 18) half the value.
In some cases you might be allowed to bring in more value if you can convince the customs people that you will take it with you when you leave the country.

In short:
I would not bring the drone if it has a value of $US 150 or over, unless you are willing to pay import duty on it.