# What is the proper way of flying from the US to Canada with a drone in my luggage?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, airport-security, x-ray-machines, drones

The drone in question is a DJI Phantom 3 Standard.

1. Can I fly with a drone at all?
2. If yes, carry-on or checked bags?
3. Do you need to declare it?
4. Do you need to take it out of bags at Security X-ray like laptops?

Comment: Which country are you planning to use the drone in?

Comment: Would the rules not be similar to a model aircraft?

Comment: You have 4 issues: TSA in the American airport, CBSA when you enter Canada, CATSA in the Canadian airport, and CBP when you enter the US

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you carry drones on a plane as a carry on? eg. DJI Phantom or Inspire](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53190/can-you-carry-drones-on-a-plane-as-a-carry-on-eg-dji-phantom-or-inspire)

Comment: The suggested dupe only addresses the first of the 4 concerns listed by @Kate Gregory, so I voted to leave open.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Using in USA; living in Canada

Comment: @KateGregory Oh boy... Sounds fun... I shouldn't have to declare it if I live in CA and purchased in CA, do I?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the remote control and the drone are off (they would probably consider those as radios/remote controlled vehicles, which are **not** allowed to be used in flight) I don't see an issue.

You will need to [register the drone with the FAA](https://registermyuas.faa.gov/) in order to fly it, and I might be wrong, but you may need an address inside the US as part of registration.

I have also checked the TSA website's tool "What Can I Bring?" for ["remote controlled helicopter"](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=remote%20control%20helicopter) and it said it could be in your carry-on or checked baggage.

However, I would avoid calling it a drone in the airport, because it says that [drones](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=drone) might not be allowed and groups them with hoverboards/self-balancing scooters because of the battery.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but from my understanding, you no longer are required to register with the FAA. And I found a source (no longer on the web unfortunately) that mentions taking a drone on Carry-On because the LiPo batteries are less exposed to temperature/pressure changes. If I find the URL of the source, I can try to find an internet archive for it.

Answer (score 3):

I've flown within the USA, to the US from Canada and Europe, and all over Europe without issues. Here are a few tips:

- Many airlines now have a drone specific page on their website -
  search using something like "can I take my drone on British Airways"
  to find it. Print this page and take it with you when you fly.
- There are likely to be limits on the amount of LiPo batteries you can
  fly with - at one stage I checked and it was three for my specific
  model on that particular airline, based on size.
- Your LiPos always have to be carried as hand luggage.
- It's advisable to discharge your batteries to around 1/3 for safety reasons. Take a look here for other handy LiPo battery handling tips: http://thedronegirl.com/2015/02/07/lipo-battery/
- It's advisable to store your LiPo batteries in a LiPo bag (available on Amazon, ebay, etc).
- Some countries don't allow drones to be imported and this could apply to passengers in transit. There's a pretty good list of applicable laws, by country, here: https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws/

I've never had a problem, other than a couple minutes delay at security as they looked over my drone (I've flown with a Phantom 4, Mavic Pro and Mavic 2 Pro) and on only one occasion did I need to nudge their approval with production of the printed "can I take my drone on __airline name____" page.