# Which airports/airlines forbid drones as carry-on in Europe?

Tags: europe, hand-luggage, prohibited-items, drones

Which airports or airlines forbid carrying consumer drones in the carry-on luggage within the EU?  [Budapest airport is one of them](http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/faq/frequently-asked-questions-about-drones-23143.html), and I would like to know if this is an isolated case, or a policy that other airports follow as well.

This question is not about batteries ([which are discussed elsewhere](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries?sort=votes)). I am specifically interested in (effective) blanket bans on drones in the hand luggage.

Related question: [Can you carry drones (eg. DJI Phantom or Inspire) on a plane as a carry on?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53190/1293)